# Broken syntax highlighting in WebStorm

Tags: ide, webstorm

I have some how changed how WebStorm sees the `div` tag. It looks like it is doing syntax highlighting for some language. Below is a screen shot of what it looks like. The file is saved as `index.html` and it is only the `div` tags that give the issue.

[image]

Any help would be great. I am not sure what other information would help, as I have no idea of what I did.

Comment: Looks like you have some language injected in `<div>` tag. Check **Settings | Editor | Language Injections** - do you have any custom injections (with **IDE** scope) there?

Comment: Thanks Iena, Thats what I had done somehow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per Iena's comment. The solution was to go into **Settings | Editor | Language Injections** and remove the div tag from the list.